# Is this serial number unique?

Tags: windows, serial-number

the one returned from on Windows machine:

```
wmic diskdrive get serialnumber
```

or can have two or more machines have same serial number?

Comment: That's the serial number of the volume you're doing the directory for, not the "Windows" serial number.

Comment: Could downvoter explain please.

Comment: @techie007: I changed a bit the questions. Check out

Comment: You need to explain what your threat model is. Do you mean "is it supposed to happen if everything goes right"? Do you mean "can someone make two machines with the same volume serial number?" Do you mean "do we actually have cases where two machines have the same volume serial number?" Or what?

Answer (score 0):

The serial number you are referring to is the volume serial number.  It belongs to the disk, not Windows.  It gets generated randomly when the volume is formatted.  If you had a D: drive it would be different.  And if you were to reformat it, it would be different yet again.

That number does not get used for anything anymore.  It's a holdover from the way things were eons ago.  And by eons ago, I mean the 1980's :-)

Comment: I changed the command-line in the question. Check out

Comment: Doesn't matter. That WMIC command just displays the exact same information.  What exactly are you trying to do with this information?